# What are some good role authorization solutions used with Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, roles

I am looking for a good role based authorization solution to use alongside Authlogic. Anyone have any good suggestions? Please list some pros and cons from your experience if possible please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acl9 works great with AuthLogic:

http://github.com/be9/acl9/tree/master

Comment: really like it. but it should totally be called yarba (yet another role based authorization - from the description).

Comment: totally =) oh yeah, about pros and cons, it's really simple to get going (the documentation makes it seem more difficult than it is). On thing that could be useful is a method to collect all the subjects for a given role. I requested for that feature but I don't know if the author put it in.

Answer (score 4):

At RailsConf, I saw a lightning talk on Lockdown and was very impressed.  Anyone with a modest amount of db and rails experience can roll their own ACL system, but Lockdown looks nice because it tries to keep the permission stuff out of the way.

http://lockdown.rubyforge.org/

I had used role_requirement previously but I didn't dig it.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently have been using a gem called easy_roles. Super light weight and super easy to use. It's also flexible enough for you to implement your own controller security etc etc.

http://github.com/platform45/easy_roles

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://blog.platform45.com/2009/10/05/howto-basic-roles-for-users for basic role requirement, works with restful_authentication and authlogic..

It's really simple, fast and lightweight.