# which is the most popular Ruby on Rails AUTHORIZATION gem/plugin at the moment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

Which is the most popular Ruby on Rails AUTHORIZATION gem/plugin at the moment?

(I am using AuthLogic for authentication by the way)

Thanks

Comment: Here's a past question with some similarity to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875595/what-are-some-good-role-authorization-solutions-used-with-authlogic

Comment: I was actually interested in the most used...but I guess it's a bit hard to judge without some sort of poll...

Comment: johnsampson's answer should be the accepted one. You asked which gem is the most popular, and that's what he answered. He also pointed to Ruby Toolbox, which lists gems by category, sorted by popularity, so I'd say that's the best place to point people who find this question from a search engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [Declarative Authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization)  There is a pretty good [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization) for it as well

Comment: Weird, link doesn't work on link click in FF3, but a copy+paste works.  Wonder if there's some referrer issue or something.

Comment: Thats so weird.  If I click on the github link in firefox I get a not found error on github, but just hitting return again in the address bar loads the page.  Clicking the same link in chrome works fine???

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about the most popular solution, but Ryan Bates (of RailsCasts fame) recently released a new authorization plugin called [CanCan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) that looks pretty easy to use and apparently integrates well with AuthLogic. Might be worth a look.

[Declarative Authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) looks quite nice as well, though I haven't used it.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look @ Ruby-Toolbox - ruby-toolbox.com.

Specifically to answer your question, **declarative_authorization** is currently the most popular.

http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization.html

They are listed in order of popularity.  Have a glance at the right column "Popularity ranks" for a quick visual view.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking to pick one of these two solutions. The main difference is the authors implementations of the same logic. DA is expressed with a DSL (like Rake) using roles, and CanCan is expressed using native Ruby includes and class methods.

I'm going to run with CanCan for now. It seems more natural and easier to work with since I use modules over Rake-style DSLs.

Ryan Bates, the author of CanCan posted this tweet, "CanCan vs Declarative Authorization...":
http://twitter.com/rbates/status/5789648368

which linked to both implementations side-by-side:
http://gist.github.com/236709